# Get EHOSTUNREACH for registry.npmjs.org IPv6 address

Tags: networking, ipv6

My laptop is running 22.04, and my DSL router allows for IPv6 addresses on the LAN.  There is not a public IPv6 address for my network, only an IPv4 address.

I am able to reach all kinds of addresses as normal.  But, if I run "npm install" or the like, including "ping registry.npmjs.org", the connection fails with EHOSTUNREACH

After running these commands, I can reach registry.npmjs.org

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
[sudo] password for david: 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I'm hoping there is a clean way to reach IPv6 addresses without disabling IPv6 support.